# Trying to get session value change when logging in

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I am having an issue trying to figure out how to get a session value for department to change when logging in. The users default value is setup in the user_info table. When they log in it grabs that and stores it in a session called dept. So that I can use through out the app. What I am trying to do is allow the user to type a new department and change the  dept session to the one they typed in the input box. I tried adding a $_Get or $_POST on the profile.php page, because once user logs in it goes to that page. I had no luck it just showed up as blank. Any help would be appreciated. I will keep trying to figure it out and post answer if I get it.

index.php

```
<div style="width: 300px;">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <label for="lanId">lanId</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lanId">
                                <label for="lanId">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
                                <input type="text" class="from-control" placeholder="change department" id="department" name="department">

                                <p><br></p>

                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="float: right;bottom:12px;" id="login" value="Login" name="login">
                            </div>
```

login.php

```
<?php 
    include('dbconnect.php');
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['userLogin'])){

        $lanId=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lanId']);
        $pwd=md5($_POST['pwd']);
        $sql="SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE lanId='$lanId' AND password='$pwd'";
        $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $count=mysqli_num_rows($run_query);

        if($count==1){
                $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query);
                $_SESSION['uid']=$row['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['uname']=$row['employee_name'];
                $_SESSION['dept']=$row['department'];
                $_SESSION['lanId']=$row['lanId'];
                echo "true";
        }

    }

 ?>
```

main.js

```
$("#login").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var lanId=$('#lanId').val();
    var pwd=$('#password').val();

    console.log(pwd);
    $.ajax({
        url: "login.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {userLogin:1,lanId:lanId, pwd:pwd},
        success: function(data){
            if(data=="true"){
                window.location.href="profile.php";
            }
        }
    })
})
```

This is the start of the profile page.
profile.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
    header('Location:index.php');
    }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to pass your department value in ajax request like below

```
$("#login").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var lanId=$('#lanId').val();
var pwd=$('#password').val();
var dept=$('#department').val();
console.log(pwd);
$.ajax({
    url: "login.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {userLogin:1,lanId:lanId, pwd:pwd,dept:dept},
    success: function(data){
        if(data=="true"){
            window.location.href="profile.php";
        }
    }
})
```

})

Then in login.php

```
<?php 
include('dbconnect.php');
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['userLogin'])){

    $lanId=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lanId']);
    $pwd=md5($_POST['pwd']);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE lanId='$lanId' AND password='$pwd'";
    $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($run_query);

    if($count==1){
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query);
            $_SESSION['uid']=$row['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['uname']=$row['employee_name'];
            $_SESSION['dept']=$row['department'];
            $_SESSION['lanId']=$row['lanId'];
            echo "true";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['dept']) && !empyt($_POST['dept']))
    {
      $_SESSION['dept']=$_POST['dept'];
    }

}

?>
```

Hopefully its work.

Comment: This worked except to get it to work I had to remove && !empyt($_POST['dept'])